# How to configure Intellj to format lists in javadoc?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, formatting, javadoc

When writing javadocs I occasionally have lists in there, i.e.

```
/**
 * <ul>
 *   <li>item1</li>
 *   <li>item2</li>
 * </ul>
 */
```

When I reformat code (`Ctrl+Alt+L`) the indentation gets removed:

```
/**
 * <ul>
 * <li>item1</li>
 * <li>item2</li>
 * </ul>
 */
```

To make things worse, as soon I have the list under a `@param` or `@throws` declaration (i.e. for listing options or cases when the exceptions get thrown) and I hit reformat code, the whole list becommes single line

```
/**
 * @throws Exception
 *         <ul> <li>item1</li> <li>item2</li> </ul>
 */
```

Which is really bad to read and maintain.

So how do I configure IntelliJ to

- ignore lists in javadoc (good)
- format lists properly with indentation in javadoc (better)
- format all html properly with indentation in javadoc (even better)

Comment: Related requests: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-128603
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-147601
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-100381
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-143120.

Comment: so the solution is to wrap it in <pre> tags !?

Comment: @GeraldMücke - I wish I could upvote your comment 1000 times!

Answer (score 3):

Adding `<pre>` solved the issue for me.

```
/**
 * <pre>
 * <ul>
 *     <li></li>
 *     <li></li>
 * </ul>
 * </pre>
 */
```

I just felt like this question should have its proper answer (although it was in the comments).